# Cannot get correct type of chart: xlColumnStacked "variant 2" through vba code

Tags: charts

I cannot assign the correct type of chart through VBA-code,
the type I need is "xlColumnStacked variant number 2"

Wanted variant

[image]

The code is run is the following:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = 52 'or synonymously  : ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
```

This do not occur if the plot is already of the stacked format (still type 52 / xlColumnStacked), either in "bar og column"-stacked mode.

However, if I change the series which are displayed in the plot, the chart goes to "default" and I struggle to find any vba-code wise way to get back to the format which I want (see picture).
The thing is that I print these, for 80 series, and I hope to make that automated...

Received vba variant

[image]

I have had the same problem with changing line style on markers in scatter plot mode too, which made the same changes to the lines (between the markers) in the scatter plott.
The problem is that the name of the object is overlapping with another name it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I (and also a helper from Microsoft) found a partial solution:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/cannot-get-correct-type-of-chart-through-vba-code/ef57be1a-fab5-42a9-8d18-4af79e0cd5b2?messageId=9f8d32f2-d53d-449f-aa44-6d076ed5a1fe